# How do I run an if loop constantly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I want to constantly run an `if` loop outside of my functions, but I can't figure out how to do it. I made a mock up of the code::

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

code = Tk()

T = 1
X = 0

def printx():
    global X
    print(X);

def teez():
    global T
    T = 0;

def teeo():
    global T
    T = 1;

if T == 1:
    X = 5
else:
    X = 6

button1 = Button(code, text = "Print X", command = printx)
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(code, text = "T = 0", command = teez)
button2.pack()
button2 = Button(code, text = "T = 1", command = teeo)
button2.pack()

code.mainloop()
```

I want the `if` loop to change `X` based on what my functions do, but the `if` loop seems to not run.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: "if loop" makes no sense. "if" is a conditional, not a loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "if loop".  `if` is a conditional statement that executes one of two branches of code, once only.  The looping statements at this level are `for` and `while`; see your favorite Python tutorials to become familiar with their usage.

Running a constant monitor loop is the wrong control flow for this.  Rather, you need only to check when the button is pressed.  Put the functionality inside your press-handling routines:

```
def teez():
    global T, X
    T = 0
    X = 6

def teeo():
    global T, X
    T = 1
    X = 5
```

I strongly question setting global variables within the code.  Instead, consider making an object with attributes `T` and `X`, and setting those as needed, passing the object to the routines that have to manipulate them.

Comment: I was about to post something similar to this. +1 for control flow considerations

Answer (score 0):

the if structure is not a loop, but a conditional statement. If you want to do something iteratively, try with `while True:`

Comment: This may prevent OP's `code.mainloop()` from executing